# kworker uses 100% cpu - please help

Tags: kernel

These problems look like they tend to be specific to an individual machine unfortunately.

All I've read so far is to use perf tools, but I'm not sure how to proceed. I'm on Ubuntu 16.10, keeping it up to do date 4.8.0-41-generic
I don't know precisely when this started or if it was a result of an upgrade.

I've tried some simple things like rebooting, turning of all background programs like dropbox etc, turning wifi off. Nothing yet helps even diagnose the issue. I can't find anything yet on what Swapper is, but if it is to do with the swap space ... i'm still not sure what I should be doing. is it corrupted? do I need to follow the instructions and make it bigger/smaller/change the priority?

```
Samples: 46K of event 'cycles:ppp', Event count (approx.): 114256689685258                                                                                                                                    
  Children      Self  Command          Shared Object                          Symbol                                                                                                                          
+   99.97%     0.00%  swapper          [kernel.kallsyms]                      [k] cpu_startup_entry
+   99.97%     0.00%  swapper          [kernel.kallsyms]                      [k] call_cpuidle
+   99.97%     0.00%  swapper          [kernel.kallsyms]                      [k] cpuidle_enter
+   99.97%     0.00%  swapper          [kernel.kallsyms]                      [k] cpuidle_enter_state
+   99.97%     0.00%  swapper          [kernel.kallsyms]                      [k] start_secondary
+   99.86%    99.86%  swapper          [kernel.kallsyms]                      [k] intel_idle
     0.11%     0.11%  swapper          [kernel.kallsyms]                      [k] poll_idle
     0.03%     0.00%  kworker/0:0      [kernel.kallsyms]                      [k] kthread
     0.03%     0.00%  kworker/0:0      [kernel.kallsyms]                      [k] ret_from_fork
     0.03%     0.00%  kworker/0:0      [kernel.kallsyms]                      [k] worker_thread
     0.03%     0.00%  kworker/0:0      [kernel.kallsyms]                      [k] process_one_work
     0.03%     0.00%  kworker/0:0      [kernel.kallsyms]                      [k] acpi_os_execute_deferred
     0.03%     0.00%  kworker/0:0      [kernel.kallsyms]                      [k] acpi_ev_asynch_execute_gpe_method
     0.03%     0.00%  kworker/0:0      [kernel.kallsyms]                      [k] acpi_ns_evaluate
     0.03%     0.00%  kworker/0:0      [kernel.kallsyms]                      [k] acpi_ps_execute_method
     0.03%     0.00%  kworker/0:0      [kernel.kallsyms]                      [k] acpi_ps_parse_aml
     0.03%     0.00%  kworker/0:0      [kernel.kallsyms]                      [k] acpi_ps_parse_loop
     0.02%     0.00%  kworker/0:0      [kernel.kallsyms]                      [k] acpi_ds_exec_end_op
     0.02%     0.00%  kworker/0:0      [kernel.kallsyms]                      [k] acpi_ds_evaluate_name_path
     0.02%     0.00%  kworker/0:0      [kernel.kallsyms]                      [k] acpi_ex_resolve_to_value
     0.02%     0.00%  kworker/0:0      [kernel.kallsyms]                      [k] acpi_ex_resolve_node_to_value
     0.02%     0.00%  kworker/0:0      [kernel.kallsyms]                      [k] acpi_ex_read_data_from_field
     0.02%     0.00%  kworker/0:0      [kernel.kallsyms]                      [k] acpi_ex_extract_from_field
     0.02%     0.00%  kworker/0:0      [kernel.kallsyms]                      [k] acpi_ex_field_datum_io
     0.02%     0.00%  kworker/0:0      [kernel.kallsyms]                      [k] acpi_ex_access_region
     0.02%     0.00%  kworker/0:0      [kernel.kallsyms]                      [k] acpi_ev_address_space_dispatch
```

Answer (score 0):

So I reduced the swap priority (called swappiness) to 0 with the following:

I added vm.swappiness=0 to the end of /etc/sysctl.conf

Has not helped.

Any other ideas?